# is there a way to find out which quicktab tab is active?

Tags: blocks

I would like to know which tab is active so I can set it to default until another tab is active then that will be set to default

my problem is that I cant seem to find a way to see which tab is active at the moment and getActiveTab seems to always return the default tab

any help well be greatly appreciated

thanks in advance

Comment: $quicktab = quicktabs_load(5); // enter your QT ID. 
$quicktab['default_tab'] contains the default tab's ID.

Comment: I cant see how this will work as I dont know the current Active tab unless its possible to put it in js onclick

Comment: Active tab may possibly have classes attached to it, so you may discover it with Firebug, detect it with jQuery ? Or you may attach your classes on active tabs with jQuery onclick, as you mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After much consideration and a ton of tries I decided to go with cookies,I added this to my script file from
http://drupal.org/node/1454486

```
Drupal.behaviors.quicktabsHistory = {
attach: function(context, settings) {
  // enable accordion memory
  $('.quick-accordion', context).each(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var accordion = $.cookie(id);

    if (accordion != '') {
      $(this).find('h3 a[href="' + accordion + '"]').click();
    }
    $(this).find('h3 a').click(function() {
      $.cookie(id, $(this).attr('href'));
    });
  });

  // enable tab memory
  $('.quicktabs-wrapper', context).each(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var tab = $.cookie(id);

    if (tab != '') {
      $(this).find('ul.quicktabs-tabs a#' + tab).click();
    }
    $(this).find('ul.quicktabs-tabs a').click(function() {
      $.cookie(id, $(this).attr('id'));
    });
  });
}
};
```

thanks for your time and efforts